# Hide 'Shop by price' left navigation only group product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to hide "Shop By Price" on category page when all product type is group .
 "Shop By Price" filter show when product type is simple product. Magento Enterprise 1.4

[image]

Comment: add more details

Comment: Hi @Rahul i have edited my question . please review it

Comment: Find the shop by price xml layout and put inside these two  <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog"> and  <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog"> thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

open your `app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Price.php`

Here check your current category product type . if all product type is group then hide this code `$items[] = $this->_createItemEx($itemData);`

Below i have show my code

Replace code

```
protected function _initItems()
    {
        $data = $this->_getItemsData();
        $items=array();
        foreach ($data as $itemData) {
            // MANA BEGIN
            $items[] = $this->_createItemEx($itemData);
            // MANA END
        }
        // MANA BEGIN: enable additional filter item processing
        /* @var $ext Mana_Filters_Helper_Extended */ $ext = Mage::helper(strtolower('Mana_Filters/Extended'));
        $items = $ext->processFilterItems($this, $items);
        // MANA END
        $this->_items = $items;
        return $this;
    }
```

To

```
protected function _initItems()
    {
        $data = $this->_getItemsData();
        $items=array();

        $categoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); 
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                         ->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $countOther = 0;
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            if($product->getTypeId() != 'grouped'){
                $countOther = $countOther + 1; 
            }
        }
        foreach ($data as $itemData) {
            // MANA BEGIN
            if($countOther > 0) {
                $items[] = $this->_createItemEx($itemData);
            }           
            // MANA END
        }
        // MANA BEGIN: enable additional filter item processing
        /* @var $ext Mana_Filters_Helper_Extended */ $ext = Mage::helper(strtolower('Mana_Filters/Extended'));
        $items = $ext->processFilterItems($this, $items);
        // MANA END
        $this->_items = $items;
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: why not used the xml file rather than modification on code ?

Comment: @Rahul actually previous developer modify this extension. when i do changes in price  xml so it's break navigation. This is my problem